# How many learnable parameters does a fully connected layer have without the bias?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Assuming I have an Input of N x N x W for a fully connected layer and my fully connected layer has a size of Y how many learnable parameters does the fc has ? The fc connects all the inputs and finds out the nonlinearaties to each other, but how does the size of the fc influence this. For simplification the bias can be ignored.

The assumed answer is: `N * N * W * Y`, cause one has to connect "everything with everything".
But it is not sure, and I could not find any proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`N * N * W * Y` weights is the correct answer. No need for proof: it directly results from the definition of a fully connected, feed-forward layer and from the fact that each connection has one weight.

You can draw some small neural networks to convince yourself if needed ([source](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/)):

[image]

[image]